# See connected device log on iTunes?

Tags: itunes

is it possible to see a history list of devices I have connected to my computer on iTunes so far? The other day I connected a device and I would like to see if that was logged somewhere.

Comment: Was this a device that you had associated to your AppleID?

Comment: No, it was somebody elses device. She asked me to update her iOS so I connected it to my computer.

Comment: I'm not finding anything that shows a log of devices that connected via iTunes.

Comment: Bad news.......

Answer (score 1):

In researching this there does not appear to be any logs or details within iTunes that will show a list of devices that have been connected to iTunes. You can view the list of devices associated with the AppleID account and the list of devices associated with iTunes and that's about it.

Guidances from Apple on this:

> You can have ten devices (no more than five of them computers)
>   associated with your Apple ID and iTunes at one time.

And this:

> The list of associated devices that you can [view in iTunes](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204074#computer) is not
>   the same as the list of devices that you're currently signed in to
>   with your Apple ID. You can check your Apple ID device list to see
>   where you're signed in on your [Apple ID account page](https://appleid.apple.com/).
>
> You don't need to associate your devices to buy content or download
>   new purchases. You can remove an associated device if:
>
> - You reach your limit of associations and want to add a new one.
> - You can't download past purchases from the iTunes Store.
> - You want to sell or give away an associated device.

#### References

- [View and remove your associated devices in iTunes](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204074)

Comment: I see. Thats some bad news right there. Thank you anyway.